Cloning Windows 10 VMs fails with Result Code: E_FAIL (0X80004005) in Virtualbox 7.0.20
I recently updated to Virtualbox 7.0.20, which I am running on Windows 10 Home.
I can create functioning Windows 10 guest VMs from an ISO (not the same image as the host machine) but attempts to make a full clone of any of the VMs fail with "Result Code: E_FAIL (0X80004005)".
If I try to launch a failed clone, this error message is displayed along with a drop down menu:

"The VM failed to boot. This is possibly caused by not having an operating system installed or a misconfigured boot order. Maybe picking a guest OS install DVD will resolve the situation"

In the drop down, I can select the ISO that was used to create the source VM, but the clone still will not launch.
None of the settings from the source VMs are copied into the clones; and some of the cloned settings seem like junk.  For instance, the source VMs have 128 MB of video memory but the clones have only 8.  The bad settings in the failed clones are always identical though.
Cloning fails even when I make a new guest from the ISO and make no changes after creation, such as running Windows Update.  I have run both:
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth and sfc /scannow on the "base" VM before cloning.
Attached is a zip of the log from one of the failed launches.  The logs are produced only when I try to launch one.  Otherwise the clone folders contain only a .vbox file after the failed clone.
Advice is appreciated.  I have the feeling this is "obvious", but I never had issues with this procedure or ISO before.strong text

You haven’t attached the logs

Thanks.  Truly thought I had.  Can't find how to attach the log file to this post :/

Ran into the same problem myself, try this
